# Null annotation processor in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, null, annotations

I'm using the Eclipse JDT Null annotation processor and I'm getting some weird behaviour when using java.lang.Class.

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.Nullable;

public class AnnotationSpul {

    @Nullable
    public <V> V get1(Class<V> type) {
        return get2(type); //This line has a warning
    }

    @Nullable
    public <V> V get2(Class<V> type) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my package info:

```
@NonNullByDefault({ PARAMETER, RETURN_TYPE, FIELD })
package test;

import static org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.DefaultLocation.FIELD;
import static org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.DefaultLocation.PARAMETER;
import static org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.DefaultLocation.RETURN_TYPE;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault;
```

The warning I get is: "The expression of type '@NonNull Class' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull Class<@Nullable V>'"

I don't understand why I get the warning. The method signatures are exactly the same, so why does the value passed need conversion? Why is `type` inferred as `@NonNull Class<V>` in one method and `@NonNull Class<@Nullable V>` in the other?

Comment: I am not very familiar with those annotations, but for me it looks like you declared to have parameters and return values _non null by default_ (in the package info). Afterwards you declare a method (and thus the return type) as _nullable_. This is obviously contradictory, isn't it? [I know, this doesn't deal with the difference between those two methods.]

Comment: I tried this using the Checker Framework's [Nullness Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-checker) and it worked as you desire.  The Nullness Checker even recognizes Eclipse's annotations.

Comment: As a matter of style, so long as you are usng a Java 8 compiler it is best to write a type annotation next to the type it modifies.  For example, use `public <V> @Nullable V get1(...)` rather than `@Nullable public <V> V get1(...)`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose it is not really contradictory, because the things in the package-info are "default" values. So you can override them in your actual classes. Or at least that's the way I understand it. if it wouldn't be the case, defining a NonNull default would disallow you to have ANY null-returning methods in a class.

Comment: @mernst regarding your first comment. Do you mean the checker framework does NOT give this warning? It differs from the Eclipse Null annotation processor?

Comment: @mernst regarding your second comment. I sort of agree with you, but for the record, the Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin (which we use) does not. It dictates annotations should precede ALL modifiers.

Comment: @DavidtenHove Yes, the Nullness Checker of the Checker Framework does not give the warning.  It is more precise than the Eclipse JDT Null Analysis, for your example.

Comment: For posterity: this was a bug in ecj, that got fixed as of 4.5M5.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann Thank you so much! If you put it in an official answer, I'll make sure to accept it. Could you provide a link to the bug as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug in ecj 4.4](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456236). In a combination of type inference and null inference ecj over-eagerly inferred the type parameter to `@Nullable V`.

The bug was fixed in [4.5M5](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.5M5-201501291830/), so the upcoming [release 4.5 (Mars)](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/mars) will accept the program as expected.